# Summing the quantities in a list of tuples

Tags: functional-programming, f#

For example, if I have a list like this:

```
[("pizza", 4); ("milkshake", 2); ("chocolate", 2); ("pizza", 3); ("milkshake", 3); ("pizza", 4)]
```

and I want to sum all the second elements of the tuples while the first tuple is the same. How should I do it?

The output should be:

```
[("pizza", 11); ("milkshake", 5); ("chocolate, 2")]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used `List.groupBy` to group the items according to the item name:

```
let items = [("pizza", 4); ("milkshake", 2); ("chocolate", 2); ("pizza", 3); ("milkshake", 3); ("pizza", 4)]
let grouped = List.groupBy fst items

// returns the following:
// [("pizza", [("pizza", 4); ("pizza", 3); ("pizza", 4)]);
//  ("milkshake", [("milkshake", 2); ("milkshake", 3)]);
//  ("chocolate", [("chocolate", 2)])]
```

This returns a list of tuples where the first entry is the item name (e.g. pizza) and the second entry is itself a list, containing all the original tuples which match that name.

Then you can map each sub-list to the sum of the second entries:

```
let summed = List.map (fun (name, entries) -> (name, entries |> List.sumBy snd)) grouped

// returns [("pizza", 11); ("milkshake", 5); ("chocolate", 2)] as expected
```

The documentation for the [List module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list-module-[fsharp]) shows all the built in functions for working with lists.

Note that `fst` and `snd` are built-in functions which return the first and second elements of a two-element tuple respectively.

Once you're more familiar with F#, you might want to use the forward pipe operator `|>` to do this more succinctly:

```
let summed =
    items
    |> List.groupBy fst
    |> List.map (fun (name, entries) -> (name, entries |> List.sumBy snd))
```